# Merge linked lists from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to solve the Merge K sorted lists[image]

Idea behind the solution:

1. Loop through the list of linkedlists and add each node to the dictionary with the value as key and node as value.
2. In case of duplicate values of linkedlists, add the node as next to the already available key in the dictionary
3. Sort the keys and loop through the dictiory to merge all the linkedlists
   Problem I am facing:

I am not able to merge back all the linked lists, following is the code:

```
def mergeKLists(self, lists: List[Optional[ListNode]]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    all={}
    if not lists or len(lists)==0:
        return None
    for node in lists:
        while(node!=None):
            temp1=ListNode()
            temp1.val=node.val
            temp1.next = None
            if(node.val in all.keys()):    
                temp = all[temp1.val]
                temp.next = temp1
                all[node.val]=temp
                temp=None
                node=node.next
                continue
                
            all[node.val]=temp1
            node=node.next
    s=sorted(all.keys())
    disp=[]        
    sol=ListNode()
    dummy = all[s[0]]

# This is where I am really stuck and don't really know what to do
# to merge back all nodes into a single linked list and return the linked list

#I got this solution to merge manually for this particular test case, but I need to put this in a loop to generalize :


sol=ListNode()
    dummy=sol
    dummy.next = all[s[0]]
    dummy = dummy.next.next
    dummy.next=all[s[1]]
    dummy = dummy.next
    dummy.next=all[s[2]]
    dummy = dummy.next
    dummy.next=all[s[3]]
    dummy = dummy.next.next
    dummy.next=all[s[4]]
    dummy = dummy.next
    dummy.next=all[s[5]]
    dummy = dummy.next
    return sol.next
```

the dictionary :

```
all= {1: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: None}}, 4: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}, 5: ListNode{val: 5, next: None}, 3: ListNode{val: 3, next: None}, 2: ListNode{val: 2, next: None}, 6: ListNode{val: 6, next: None}}
```

[image: Input-Output-expected:]

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No errors but the output is not what I had expected

Comment: Show the output you got, and the expected output. But more importantly, add more print statements to your code, so you can debug it yourself. Start with very simple test cases. As each list element is processed, what happens - does it find a matching key or not? If it finds a matching key, print the list of matches for that key. Add print statements until you can see exactly what is going on, for different test inputs.

Comment: I tried everything that you have mentioned, the only problem I am facing is : I am not able to figure how to merge the nodes from the dictionary I created.

Comment: **Show the output you got, and the expected output.** - Add this information to your question.

Comment: I recommend writing some simple test cases for the piece of code that does not work. Work with it, separate from the problem itself. For example, given `s= [1, 2]; all = {1: ListNode(1), 2: ListNode(2)}`, what happens? Suppose `n11 = ListNode(1); n11.next = ListNode{1}; all =  {1: n11, 2: ListNode(2)}`? I think you'll discover that you are working incorrectly with all three of these: `dummy`, `sol = sol.next`, and `all[i].next`. print statements should allow you to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution ended up in an infinite loop because of this `dummy = all[i].next`. It will never become `None` and the loop will never end.

You can use below code for creating a linked list from the dict

```
dummy = sol = ListNode()
for key in sorted(all):
    dummy.next = all[key]
    while dummy.next:
        dummy = dummy.next

sol = sol.next
```